# How to render three shadows on mapbox using mesh from Terrain-DEM

Tags: three.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using mapbox to create a context for building models. The buildings are rendered as meshed using three which makes it possible to draw realistic shadows and even calculate the exact shadow for a specific time since I have a geographical location for my building model. The way I do this is to place a three scene on top of the mapbox canvas with a invisible ground plane, a `PlaneGeometry` that still recieves shadows, on the ground level.

Now I want to use the 3D terrain in mapbox to be able to place the buildings at the right altitude as well for a specific location. To do so I've had a look at the [mapbok terrain tilesets](https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/reference/mapbox-terrain-dem-v1/) to create a mesh that I can project the buildings to before I add them to the scene.

I've started to implement this but I have a few concerns. First of all, since the terrain is above the ground level, I won't be able to use the [ground plane to render the shadows of the buildings any more,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZVUN.png).

What I instead would like to see is that the shadow gets rendered **ON** the mapbox terrain, but this is no easy task since the shadow lives only in the three scene and not in the mapbox canvas. What I was thinking was that I could use the tiles to create a three mesh clone of the surrounding area and let that recieve the shadow.

Now to the question:

Since the tileset is a raster based data format, I'll get a grid of elevation points that I need to convert into a mesh that matches the mapbox webgl terrain really close for the render to look good. Moreover, if I manage to create a perfect match, this mesh needs to be translated ever so slightly up to avoid z-clipping. Mapbox is however [interpolating](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#interpolate) the raster values to create a [smooth texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFUao.jpg) for the terrain. My question is if you have suggestions on how to do this interpolation to get the best possible match with the topography in mapbox or if you have other suggestions for how to achieve this.

Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify what I mean a bit further. This image shows what the mesh looks like when I use the RGB-treeain tileset to create a mesh that I render on the map with 3d terrain toggled on. In this case I use a cubic interploation from 256 to 40 points in each direction to smoothen the mesh. You can see that (at least partly) because of the wrong interpolation algorithm, the created mesh does not match so well with the 3d terrain in mapbox.  Image: https://ibb.co/JWLYgqQ